# mysql trigger used with load data infile

Tags: mysql, triggers, load-data-infile

I have been having a hard time figuring out how to make 'table2' update its values based on the values in 'table1' whenever new rows are inserted in 'table1'. Depending on what is being inserted into table1, the trigger may need to insert new rows in table 2, or just update values in existing rows in table2. I insert a couple thousand rows into 'table1' at a time using 'load data infile' and text files. If possible I would like the update on table 2 to occur after the entire file is inserted in to 'table1', not after each row is inserted. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below I have included the definition from table1 and what I need in table2.

```
//Table1
create table table1 (
V1 varchar(5),
V2 varchar(5),
V3 date,
V4 double,
V5 date,
V6 double,
V7 double,
Primary Key (V1,V2,V3,V4,V5) );

//Table2
V1 - Same as table1
V2 - Same as table1
V3 - Same as table1
V4 - Same as table1
V5 date - minimum of V5 in table1
V6 date - maximum of V5 in table1
```

Comment: I have decided to go a different route. I discovered a limitation of MySQL triggers is that they have to execute after every row, and if you are inserting a couple thousand rows at a time using 'load data infile' this will create significant overhead. Instead I wrote a short little method that my java app runs just once, after the entire file is inserted in the database.

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer to my own question, I found out that as of MySQL release 5.6 (the newest version) triggers can only be configured to run after each row is inserted. If `load data infile` is being used, the trigger can not be configured to run just after the entire file is inserted instead of after each row.

Hopefully this will be expanded later. As the syntax stands right now, when you create a trigger, you have to include the phrase `FOR EACH ROW`. If you omit the phrase you will get an error, but there are no other options such as `FOR EACH 10 ROWS` or `FOR EACH FILE`.